# File save within IDE save to multiple file locations

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012, ide

Due to a source control folder structure that is out of my control I have found myself in a situation where I need to keep my source python files in three separate locations up-to-date at all times. I am looking for the cleanest solution to accomplish this without having to resort to hacking it together.

- I have all of my primary python source files and my Visual Studio 2012 Python Tools project files in a folder that is not published to the end user, but is managed via source control.
- I have all of my python files updated into a separate folder that is published to the end users. Files contained in this folder are not ever executed, only used to publish into final builds.
- I have a local folder that these python files will end up in if I download a published build. Unfortunately when executing the main application from the published build, this is the folder that the python files will be executed via.

Obviously this is a simplified explanation of the problem. However my goal is to cleanly be able to save a file while editing in Visual Studio 2012 Python Tools, and have it distribute to PublishFiles, and DestinationFiles. Very similar to how in any C++ project you would have an output directory.

My first reaction to this question would be to not work in this fashion, unfortunately I do not have any control over this situation, only need to develop a solution to the problem.

Thanks!